# Netsuite problem rendering an Advanced PDF with current record data via Suitelet 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

**The Problem:** I need to create a dummy packing slip from an open sales order for drop-ship customers.

**Step 1:** I've made a user-event button that calls this client-script click handler:

```
define(['N/url', 'N/currentRecord'], function (url, currentRecord) {
    function pageInit(context) {
    }

 function onButtonClick() {
    var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
        scriptId: 'customscript_zg_drop_packingslip_pdf', // my suitelet script id
        deploymentId: 'customdeploy_zg_drop_packingslip_pdf', // my suitelet deployment id
        returnExternalUrl: false,
      params: {
            custom_id: currentRecord.get().id,
        },
    });

    window.open(suiteletUrl);
}

    exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
    exports.pageInit = pageInit;
    return exports;
});
```

**Step 2:** I'm stuck on the suitelet. I want it to pull data from the current record and pass it through an Advanced PDF template to create my drop-ship packing slip in a new window.

```
define(['N/render', 'N/record', 'N/xml'],
function(render, record, xml) {
  function onRequest(context) {
    var id = context.request.parameters.custom_id;
    if (!id) {
        context.response.write('The parameter "custom_id" is required');
        return;
    }
        var renderer = render.create(id);
        renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("CUSTTMPL_128_3768700_732"); // The ID of my Packing Slip Advanced PDF Template
        var myPdf = context.response.write(renderer.templateContent);
    }
    return {
      onRequest:onRequest
    }
})
```

The current output is not showing up as a pdf, it stretches and scales with the browser window. And instead of passing my current record data through it, I only get the schema-browser token ids. It currently looks like this:

[image: Fig 1]

But I want it to look like this (as my Advanced PDF Template actually looks), with real data from the current sales order, and as an in-browser pdf which I can save, print, and email. I do not need to create or store these files in the file cabinet:

[image: Fig2]
How do I get my suitelet to pull the open order data and render it as a pdf from my template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to generate a PDF file, you must use:

```
context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf());
```

Also the renderer.create function doesn't accept an "id" : you will find good examples on how to generate the PDF file here: https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4412042824.html

An example is :

```
var renderer = render.create();
renderer.addRecord('saleorder', record.load({
    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
    id: context.request.parameters.custom_id
}));
renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("CUSTTMPL_128_3768700_732");
context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf());
```

Comment: This looks like it should work, but when I plug this in to my onRequest(context) function, I'm getting the following error: {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: type","stack":["createError(N/error)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/ss2-add-button/ZGDropPackingSlipPDF.js:45)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: type"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

Comment: There is a typo, it should be record.Type.SALES_ORDER not record.Type.SALE_ORDER

Comment: Thanks @RustyShackles : fixed (I did it from memory)

Comment: I've updated the code to 'salesorder' and 'SALES_ORDER' and still get errors. Here's [a screenshot of the full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE1yZ.png). And a screenshot of [the resulting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg508.png).

Comment: Well, the error you are getting is in file ZGDropPackingSlipPDF.js line 45 and in your screenshot, there is no line 45 : so it seems you have an error else where: probably with your template code.

Comment: SOLVED! There was a barcode on the footer of the pdf template trying to pull ${record.tranid}. I commented that out to test and it works perfectly! Thank you both for your help & patience. Now I'll make sure that we won't ever need to scan a barcode on that particular form.

Comment: One weird hiccup that I'm now trying to debug is that this works perfectly for open sales orders when the status is pending fulfillment, but throws errors when the order has been fulfilled and the status changes to billed. The advanced template is a "packing slip" type, and I can use 'sales order' or 'invoice' templates from the closed order to make a faux packing slip, but they aren't pulling the data, my salesorder.item list returns empty. Just something to be aware of, for future problem solvers trying to replicate this process. I'll comment again with my solution, when I find one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Help docs, render.create does not expect the id parameter.

Try the following

```
var renderer = render.create();
renderer.addRecord({
    templateName: 'record',
    record: record.load({
        type: <recordtype>,
        id: <recordid>
        });
    });

var invoicePdf = renderer.renderAsPdf();
```

Comment: There's also `render.pickingTicket()` that may work.

Comment: Plugging this in with 'record.Type.SALE_ORDER,' as my type and 'context.request.parameters.custom_id' as my id, I get the error: Cannot call method "_addToTemplateRenderer" of undefined (/SuiteScripts/ss2-add-button/ZGDropPackingSlipPDF.js#54) -- same error regardless of renderAsPdf(); or pickingTicket();

Comment: If it helps, [here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuLR7.png) of how I'm plugging this in.